# JSP: Pass Special Characters in response.setHeader?

Tags: java, jsp

I am getting stuck in a basic JSP Operation. I want to a new line so i have added \n in the end but it throws me an exception. If i remove **\n** everything works fine

**Exception**

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid LF not followed by whitespace
```

**Class File**

```
StringBuilder junitLog = new StringBuilder();
junitLog.append("The class that is being executed : " + description.getClassName() +"\n");
junitLog.append("Number of testcases to execute : " + description.testCount()+"\n");

    /**
     * @return the junitLog
     */
    public StringBuilder getJunitLog() {
        return junitLog;
    }

    /**
     * @param junitLog the junitLog to set
     */
    public void setJunitLog(StringBuilder junitLog) {
        this.junitLog = junitLog;
    }
```

**JSP:-**

```
response.setHeader("finalJUNITReport",""+ junitListener.getJunitLog());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I howeva suceeded in my requirement. :)
As clearly stated by Serge Ballesta.

**If you put a new line in a header value, anything that would follow would be considered as a new header.**.

So below is the logic i applied based on my requirement.

Below were my code changes:

```
junitLog.append("The class that is being executed : " + description.getClassName() +"?");
junitLog.append("Number of testcases to execute : " + description.testCount()+"?");
```

I added a question mark at the end of the string. THe string became something as mentioned below.

```
The class that is being executed  : testCreateHaulier?    Number of testcases to execute : 39?
```

I passed the String from JSP using response.setHeader Code as below:

```
response.setHeader("finalJUNITReport",""+ junitListener.getJunitLog());
```

and in my java class file i did something like this:

```
junitReportString=yc.getHeaderField("finalJUNITReport").toString();
System.out.println(junitReportString);
junitReportString=junitReportString.replaceAll("\\?", "\n");
System.out.println("Report Details     ==============>"+junitReportString);
```

Using replaceAll i replaced all question marks to new line and my requirement was done.
Hope it helps others too.:)

Answer (score 1):

try Base64 encoding them before you set in headers and Base64 decoding them when you want to read them back.

Answer (score 1):

As long as you think to it in the OO way, you can wonder why you couldn't put new line in your headers.

But as soon as you think that it will be transmitted using HTTP protocol, it becomes evident : a HTTP message (request or response) is nothing else than a sequential serie of bytes. For HTTP, the header section comes first and is composed of lines like that :

```
HEADER_NAME: header value
```

If you put a new line in a header value, anything that would follow would be considered as a new header. And if you put 2 consecutive new lines that would denote the end of the header section.

All you can do is to use `"\n "`, because a line beginning with a space if supposed to be a continuation line.

That's the reason of the error message *Invalid LF not followed by whitespace*, and hopefully it was there, because you would have send an incorrect header section what could be harder to detect ...